# Google-earth has stop running

Tags: google-earth

When run from Terminal I get this

```
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libmeasure.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libmeasure.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libprintmodule.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libprintmodule.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libwebbrowser.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libwebbrowser.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libgps.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libgps.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libbasicingest.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libbasicingest.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libsearchmodule.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libsearchmodule.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libinput_plugin.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libinput_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libflightsim.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libflightsim.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
Failed to load "/opt/google/earth/free/libviewsync.so" because "/opt/google/earth/free/libviewsync.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files"
zaax@Tower:~$ ^C
zaax@Tower:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this discussion.
http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2148211.html

They say:

You can try

gksudo -k -u root /opt/google/earth/free/google-earth %f

or

1. Edit sudoers file:

gksudo gedit /etc/sudoers

-add this line:

yourusername ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/the/command

remplace 
/path/to/the/command 
with 
/opt/google/earth/free/google-earth

2. Run your app in launcher or terminal with:

sudo google-earth